# How to execute a function just once

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function as part of a bigger javascript file which executes a function based on `setInterval()`. Now although it is using interval, I do want it to execute but only once but based on the code it's executing every `20`.

```
TINY.height=function(){
    return{
        set:function(e,h,s,d){
            e=typeof e=='object'?e:$(e); var oh=e.offsetHeight, ho=e.style.height||TINY.style.val(e,'height');
            ho=oh-parseInt(ho); var hd=oh-ho>h?-1:1;
                    clearInterval(e.si);
                    e.si=setInterval(function(){TINY.height.tw(e,h,ho,hd,s)},20)
        },
        tw:function(e,h,ho,hd,s){
            var oh=e.offsetHeight-ho;
            if(oh==h){clearInterval(e.si)}else{if(oh!=h){e.style.height=oh+(Math.ceil(Math.abs(h-oh)/s)*hd)+'px'}}
        }
    }
}();
```

What do I modify to only executes once and then clear out the interval?

Comment: use setTimeout instead of setInterval

Comment: ultra-simple solution: global variable that you use as a flag to signal when the function's been executed.

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly what `setTimout()` does.